# Does bioluminescence occur in humans too?

Tags: human-biology, bioluminescence

I [read](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0006256) that Japanese researchers have developed very sensitive camera that recorded bioluminescence in humans; is it possible and if so what is the mechanism behind it?

Comment: I assume blackbody radiation doesn't count?

Comment: We have more bacterial cells than eukaryotic cells in our bodies, so maybe some of them are bioluminescent?

Answer (score 14):

From the article you linked:

> virtually all living organisms emit extremely weak light, spontaneously without external photoexcitation. This biophoton emission is categorized in different phenomena of light emission from bioluminescence, and **is believed to be a by-product of biochemical reactions in which excited molecules are produced from bioenergetic processes that involves active oxygen species**

They reference these two works. The first is a 1988 review from Popp et al. (1988):

[Biophoton emission](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3396653) - Experientia 44:543–600. (sorry, I cannot find the link to a full text...)

[Fritz-Albert Popp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz-Albert_Popp) is the biophysicist who first developed the [*biophoton theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophoton).

The second work they reference is by the same first author:

[In vivo imaging of spontaneous ultraweak photon emission from a rat's brain correlated with cerebral energy metabolism and oxidative stress.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10498336) - Kobayashi M, et al.

Finally, a [search in Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=biophoton%20emission) reveals various other articles by different authors studying different species.